# jQuery offset returns invalid value for <span> or inline <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position

I've created a test case, please check it out as it illustrates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jAD2W/6/ (reduced example thanks to @patrick dw)

*For completeness, this code has also been added to the bottom of this post.*

Basically, whenever I get the offset of a span element or inline div element, the `top` value is larger than it should be.

When you mouse-over the image in the example, it should stay at that absolute position. Unfortunately, it appears to be moved down.

What is causing it to move down? Removing the span element solves the problem, which indicates that it is caused by the inline property of the span element. Unfortunately, I do need the entire thing to be contained by a span or an inline div element.

The code from jsFiddle (html, javascript, css):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id='showArea'>
        <span id="containerElement1">
             <img src='http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/5lkmac.jpg' >
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


$('#containerElement1').mouseenter(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': offset.top,
        'left': offset.left
    });
});

img {
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
}
span {
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Please place the relevant code in your question. StackOverflow is meant to be a self contained repository of questions and answers. Your question may help future readers, but if jsFiddle is down or your fiddle no longer exists, there'll be no way to reference the original issue.

Comment: @patrick dw, point taken, I added the source.

Comment: @tom maybe because thats what abosulute positions do when you give it a left and top ?

Comment: @tom, if i mousover the first element, it disappear. What do you expect to happen on mouseenter?

Comment: I don't know what is causing it, but [here's a reduced code example](http://jsfiddle.net/jAD2W/5/) that may help someone else locate the answer. This narrows it down to code to that is relevant to the actual issue so there's not so much to look at.

Comment: thanks @patrick dw, now linking to an even further reduced version of your improvement (the anchor was not needed either) @Nicola Peluchetti, the expected behavior is for the image to remain at the exact same position (while other images do move since this image is no longer static in front of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that as soon as you give the elements "position: absolute", you change a bunch of stuff about the layout. For starters, the `<span>` elements are just "position: static" and "display: inline". Because they're inline, the "top" value looks big because they're set on a text baseline that's at the bottom of their container.  The container `<div>` is stretched around them, in other words, and the top is the top of the row of text (non-existent in your example, but that's what the browser thinks).

When you flip them to "position: absolute", the meaning of those things changes.

If you start things off with a CSS rule that gives the spans "display: inline-block", then the behavior changes (though it's still somewhat weird). (*edit* — ah, it's the "text-align: center" that's doing the horizontal movement.  Once the first element is yanked out of the line, the other has to re-center itself.)

Note that when you add the spans, giving them a height has no effect; they're inline elements, not blocks.

*edit* — I've thought about how to do this, but it's a little tricky because it's not clear what effect you want.  The problem is that the rules of layout for the inline content will affect the images and cause odd behavior.  That "text-align: center", for example, will move things around as soon as you "pin" an image.  Thus, with "inline-block", when you move over an element it will freeze in place, but the other image will then be adjusted to obey that "text-align" rule, and thus overlap the pinned one.

Comment: I realize there are differences between an absolute and static element. However, isn't the point of offset() to return the absolute position of an element, even if it is static? Following this logic, setting that position to the element after changing it's positioning the absolute, should make it remain at exactly the same position. Am I wrong here?

Comment: It *is* returning the absolute position of the element. The problem is that you're idea of what that means is different than that of the browser. Elements that are "inline" have no meaningful height, so their position is along the text baseline in their containing block-level element.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Would the most senseful solution be to set the position of the new absolute span to the offset position of the image? Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jAD2W/7/ - or is it not recommended to make a span absolute and set it's height? Edit: a better solution seems to be to set a div to ```display: inline-block;```, like you suggested.

Comment: I'll update my answer so Stackoverflow doesn't complain about comment threads getting long.

Comment: Thanks. The overlap is behavior that I expected. It sounds like I expected inline to behave like inline-block. It's  shame that ```inline-block``` is not implemented in IE6 and only partly in IE7, but I believe it's the right way of tackling this issue.