# Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="scale(NaN) translate(NaN, NaN)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jvectormap

I am trying to use jVectorMap in an application and I'm receiving this error.

The example shown on their website says that all you have to do is put, `$('#map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});` on your page.

Well, I have both a div with an id of map as well as this script loaded, and I am getting this error. What is ? I'm guessing it has something to do with SVG or some setting that isn't being set (like height or width?)

Here's my use of the script:

```
<script>
  $('#map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
</script>
```

And my div:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

How do I set the height/width of the div? Or do I set this value in vectormap, or is it something else entirely?

Here is how my header scripts are organized:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css" />
<script src="jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
```

Comment: the width and height you can set either using CSS `#map {width:100px;height:100px;}` or style attribute `style="width:100px;height:100px;"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery offset returns invalid value for <span> or inline <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583586/jquery-offset-returns-invalid-value-for-span-or-inline-div)

Comment: did you find an asnwer?

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be a combination of typo from my side, and weird behaviour of jvectormap.  It turns out that when I specified invalid id within ` $('#id-which-doesnt-exist').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});`  instead of giving a clear error message that that this id doesn't exist. jvectormap simply picked first child of the `<body>`. (And that child was a regular <h1> element which had no width/height explicitly set. Later jvectormap tries to scale this element and as it doesn't have explicit size set, it fails with sizes of 0,0

Answer (score 0):

use [{x: 0, y: 1}] instead of [[0,1]]

usually this ends up being the cause of this error